# convolve and deconvolve two arrays

Tags: python, convolution

So I am trying to figure out how to get convolve and deconvolve to work properly. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
b = np.array([1,2,1])

aconvolved = signal.convolve(np.sin(a), b)
adeconvolved = signal.deconvolve(aconvolved, b)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, np.sin(a), 'g')
plt.plot(a, aconvolved[0], 'r')
plt.plot(a, adeconvolved[0], 'b')
plt.draw()
```

When I convolve "a" about a single point (like b = [2]), instead of an array, it works just fine. But when I attempt to do it about more than 1 point, or an array, it just doesn't work. I receive errors such as:

```
"ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"
```

I get this same error if I instead use:

```
a = np.arange(1, 50, 1)
b = np.array([1,2,1])
```

Even though in this case, I know they do both start at 1. If I do the same thing, but with

```
b = np.array([1,2,1])
```

I get an error of:

```
"ValueError: BUG: filter coefficient a[0] == 0 not supported yet"
```

Anyone have any tips for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not get the error where you'd think you get it. This works:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
b = np.array([1,2,1])

aconvolved = signal.convolve(np.sin(a), b)
adeconvolved = signal.deconvolve(aconvolved, b)[0]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, np.sin(a), 'g')
plt.plot(a, aconvolved[1:-1], 'r') 
plt.plot(a, adeconvolved, 'b')
plt.draw()
```

The differences:

- convolution creates some extra samples to the ends, hence the `aconvolved[1:-1]` (if you do not want to do this, then use keyword argument `mode='same'` for the `convolve` to receive a vector which has the same length as the input, but then that'll cause problems with the deconvolution output length).
- deconvolution returns a tuple, where the actual result is the first part, hence `signal.deconvolve(aconvolved, b)[0]`

Comment: Awesome, that does work so I see a little of what I was doing wrong. Still, if I try to alter the same example for more resolution I get the same first error of x and y having different first dimensions. Using: "a = np.arange(0, 50, .5)" and "b = np.array([1,1.5,2, 1.5, 1])"

Comment: That length correction depends on the length of your filter. As your filter length is now 5, you need to remove 2 samples from both ends: `aconvolved[2:-2]`. The output length is (in this mode) <input length> + <filter length> - 1, in this case 50+5-1 = 54.